# How to view Xdebug configuration

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have some troubles with configuring remote debugging with PhpStorm.

In my docker container I checked `XDEBUG_CONFIG` environment variable and it seems to be correct:

```
remote_host=192.168.227.3 remote_enable=1 remote_port=9003
```

But running `php -r "xdebug_info();"` doesn't show me neither that nor what is written in php.ini.

```
dev@e4a4f0816e54:/var/www$ php -r "xdebug_info();" | grep remote
dev@e4a4f0816e54:/var/www$
```

Though, it loads ini file:

```
                                 Settings                                 
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

How do I get built Xdebug configuration?

Comment: So what does it show? Show the whole `xdebug_info();` output (captured in the same way that you are trying to debug: a web page or a CLI).

Comment: run `php --version` and check the version of XDebug is at least 3, xdebug_info function is  introduced in ver.3

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed the problem. Xdebug3 uses different configuration from 2-nd version.
Currently, `xdebug.client_host` and `xdebug.client_port` should be used.